# How to use angularJS with WCF result

Tags: wcf, angularjs

I have a WCF service defined as follows, which I know is working (producing a valid result):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="XXX.CES.Applet")]
public interface IAppletService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "GetDefinitionJSON")]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetDefinitionJSON?request={jsonRequest}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetAppletDefinitionJSON(string jsonRequest);
}
```

I have the following controller defined, can verify that it is reaching the service and that the response is what I expect it to be (a JSON string) using FireBug:

```
angular.module('Applet',['ngResource']);
function AppletController($scope,$resource) {
  $scope.url = 'http://localhost/CESAppletService/AppletService.svc/:action';
  $scope.appletRequest =
  {
    AppletName: 'FPTotalForgeTime',
    ModelName: 'CES_ProtoType_Rings_Model',
    EntityName: 'ForgeWCTimes_ForgeTimeTotal',
    EntityType: 'Decimal',
    Value: ''
  };
  $scope.getDefinition = $resource($scope.url,
    {action:'GetDefinitionJSON',request:angular.toJson($scope.appletRequest),callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'});
  $scope.AppletInputs = $scope.getDefinition.get();
}
```

When I look at the resulting $scope.AppletInputs in FireBug or by rendering them in the page, the object looks like the following (only partial):

"""
    1
    "{"
    2
    "\"
    3
    """
    4
    "A"
    5
    "p"
    6
    "p"
    7
    "l"
    8
    "e"
    9
    "t"
    10
    "I"
    11
    "n"
    12
    "p"
    13
    "u"
    14
    "t"
    15
    "s"
    16
    "\"
    17
    """
    18

The actual service result is:

```
"{\"AppletInputs\":[{\"AllowedValues\":  [],\"EntityName\":\"Forge_OD\",\"InputLabel\":\"OD\",\"InputType\":\"Decimal\",\"Value\":null},{\"AllowedValues\":[],\"EntityName\":\"Forge_ID\",\"InputLabel\":\"ID\",\"InputType\":\"Decimal\",\"Value\":null},{\"AllowedValues\":[],\"EntityName\":\"Forge_Face\",\"InputLabel\":\"Face\",\"InputType\":\"Decimal\",\"Value\":null},{\"AllowedValues\":[\"G43400XXX\",\"S30403XXX\",\"S31603XXX\",\"N06625XXX\",\"A96061XXX\",\"G43400GE2\",\"E16587M01\"],\"EntityName\":\"MaterialGrade\",\"InputLabel\":\"Grade\",\"InputType\":\"List\",\"Value\":null}],\"AppletName\":\"FPTotalForgeTime\",\"AppletType\":\"Decimal\",\"AppletVersion\":\"\",\"EntityName\":\"ForgeWCTimes_ForgeTimeTotal\",\"ModelName\":\"CES_Prototype_Rings_Model\"}"
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?  I REALLY want to be able to use Angular for this project, but this is eating my lunch.

Comment: I haven't had this issue but are you allowed to change the service? If so try returning an object instead of a string (which is presumably being serialized to JSON in code) similar to the example in this blog: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec. You might also want to use fiddler to check if the http headers are consistent between a working version and your AngularJS call.

Comment: Actually after much testing and fiddling, I realized that for some reason, the return string on the client side is wrapped in an extra pair of quotes.  So the angular.fromJson call returned the inner string.  Still don't understand the cause, but doing angular.fromJson(angular.fromJson(response)) works!